# Kotlin inherit problem. look at the [Q.] part

Tags: kotlin

How can it use super? It doesn't have override.

I learned that if I want to drag SUPER CLASS into LOWER CLASS and modify method, I have to add [override]. but that [fun bite] doesn't have.

look at the Q. part

```
open class Charator(var hp: Int, val power: Int) {

    fun attack(charator: Charator, power: Int = this.power) {
        charator.defense(power)
    }

    open fun defense(damage: Int) {
        hp -= damage
        if (hp > 0) println("${javaClass.simpleName}'s hp is $hp ")
        else println("die")
    }
}


class SuperMonster(hp: Int, power: Int) : Charator(hp, power) {
    fun bite(charator: Charator) {   **------> Q. HOW CAN USE super EVEN DO NOT HAVE override ?**
                                                
        super.attack(charator, power + 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please edit this to proper English? i can't understand anything, except "how can it use super" and the answer is: because it has a super class.

Comment: There is no rule that you can't call super methods unless you are overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the keyword `super` when you call the `attack(..)`-method. Just call `attack(charator, power + 2)`. You only have to check, that the attack method in the `Charator` class is not private (public is the default visibility in Kotlin, so it will work).
The `super` is only needed if you override a function und want to call the overwritten method from the father class. But for your `bite` method is is not the case.